# MAMP localhost not working

Tags: localhost, mamp

I have a problem with MAMP, when I try and visit a url such as `http://localhost/discoversolar` it does not work.

However if I visit `http://streetcrime/discoversolar` it works. I may have previously set up an alias or something but I have no idea how or where I did this.

Can anyone point me in the direction of changing this back to localhost so that it works?

I have looked in `/etc/hosts`, `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` and `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` but failed to find anything.

In `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` it even states ServerName `localhost:80`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I was just going through this issue. I couldn't get my localhost to populate and I remembered editing the HOSTS file in /etc/hosts ..

I had commented the following out:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

Add into your host file and it should work :)

Hope this helps! Regards!

UPDATE:

MAMP works via port 8888 .. Try

```
http://locahost:8888
```

Answer (score 0):

probably this is what you have lost

> Open BBEdit or TextWrangler (a free, cut-down version of BBEdit
>   available from www.barebones.com). From the File menu, select Open
>   Hidden. In the Open dialog box, select All Files from the Enable
>   drop-down menu. Then navigate to Macintosh HD:private:etc:hosts, and
>   click Open.

see http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_leopard.php

hope this helps